# How to save tensorflow model with best weights

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm training an LSTM, and for portion of epochs (range not consistent) during the 300 epoch training sequence it exhibits very good accuracy, for a significant length of time. I want to be able to save the entire model at this point, but can't seem to find a way to do it except to use checkpoints and then restore and save the new model.

Is there a way I can use model.save to only capture the model when it had its best weights?

Comment: How would you know that your model has the best weights before the next steps? I feel like if you wanted to use model.save that way you could do it every epoch and keep it only if the results are better than the last previous epochs, but that would be similar to how you would implement checkpoints.

Comment: @user14518362 As with checkpoints, I'm hoping to save based on validation loss or some similar metric.

Comment: It doesn't really matter now since you have an answer, but my point was more about how validation loss or the other metric you would you could only be calculated after training and so it wouldn't be much different from having a checkpoint after each epoch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `save _best_only` argument:

```
model_checkpoint_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath=checkpoint_filepath,
    save_weights_only=True,
    monitor='val_accuracy',
    mode='max',
    save_best_only=True)
```

Comment: Somehow I missed the save_weights_only argument, which can be set to true to save the entire model. Thanks.